# Getting (500) Internal Server Error when calling restful webservice

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

When i run the below code I am getting error like ex = {"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."} can anyone help me how to fix this issue...

```
 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://project.i-engage.org/tasks/webservices/bugnetservices.asmx/GetCategories?ProjectID=17") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("rolland", "409cleaner");
    request.ContentType = "application / json; charset = utf - 8";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(soap);
        }
    }

    // Get response  
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        // Get the response stream  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        // Console application output  
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Comment: Not without seeing the server code, or a detailed message on the server. Can you check the Event Viewer on the server?

Comment: @jrummell ... i didnt find anything on the server

Comment: i didnt understand you. I am using restful architecture here..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCategories xmlns="http://bugnetproject.com/">
      <projectId>string</projectId>
    </GetCategories>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Answer (score -2, accepted):

its problem with webservice...they are not returning auth cookie.. now its working fine.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Can you add some more details to your answer perhaps?